# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key bound to thread

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, database-connection

This problem occurs time-to-time on our production server in moments of quite heavy concurrent request load (think so, but not sure). And unfortunately we cannot reproduce it for debugging...
As you can see we use `OpenSessionInViewFilter` in the filter chain. 
DAOs, no annotations.

I read about this effect at SpringSource Jira issues https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-3693 but this seems to be far away fixed bug since we use Spring version *3.1.2.RELEASE*.

I'll appreciate any ideas how to reproduce this case or fix it.

Transaction definition is nothing special (but the error falls out on `getTransaction` ):

```
    DefaultTransactionDefinition td = new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);
    td.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_DEFAULT);
    TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(td);
```

The error stack cause:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1ff8c2a] bound to thread ["http-apr-83"-exec-3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:209)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.suspend(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:115)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doSuspendSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:666)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.suspend(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:569)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:363)
    at com.havilog.baltic.cheetah.services.RtMovementsServiceImpl.moveDone(RtMovementsServiceImpl.java:867)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor798.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$JdkHandler.invoke(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:416)
    at org.apache.wicket.proxy.$Proxy8.moveDone(Unknown Source)
    at com.havilog.baltic.cheetah.rf.visual.pages.movements.refill.EnterQuantity.setLocationQty(EnterQuantity.java:378)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor820.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver$MethodGetAndSet.setValue(PropertyResolver.java:1185)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver$ObjectAndGetSetter.setValue(PropertyResolver.java:641)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver.setValue(PropertyResolver.java:143)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.AbstractPropertyModel.setObject(AbstractPropertyModel.java:186)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.setDefaultModelObject(Component.java:3068)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.setModelObject(FormComponent.java:1498)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.updateModel(FormComponent.java:1059)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$FormModelUpdateVisitor.component(Form.java:221)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$FormModelUpdateVisitor.component(Form.java:192)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:273)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrder(Visits.java:244)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.visitComponentsPostOrder(FormComponent.java:388)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.internalUpdateFormComponentModels(Form.java:1763)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.updateFormComponentModels(Form.java:1728)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:900)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:757)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:692)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor374.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:260)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:784)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:188)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:284)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:322)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1714)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Yes, this sounds obviously. In our case it's quite hard to provide all necessary conditions and the data for a real load test that emulates the real work process. The problem appears once in 2-3 days and even big loads may not guarantee it.

Comment: did you finally fix that? any suggestion? I'm facing the same issue :(

Comment: Yes, it was fixed. But there is no exact solutions that I could provide. In my case the reason was uncatched exit from the transaction scope in one of concurrent threads. Check if there are any exceptions that potentially can cause something like that.